# Javascript method to capitalize the first letter of every word and also every word after hyphen or dash

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, lookbehind

I need a JavaScript method to allows me to convert the first letter of every word in a string to a capital letter like this: `mike tyson wayne` to `Mike Tyson Wayne`.
The method should also be able to convert the first word after an hyphen to capital letter like this: `mike-tyson wayne` to `Mike Tyson Wayne`.
The method should also be able to convert uppercase words to capitalize words like this: `MIKE-TYSON WAYNE` to `Mike Tyson Wayne`.

I have tried this method using regular expression gotten from another thread:

```
text.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase())
```

- (^\w{1}): match first char of string
- |: or
- (\s{1}\w{1}): match one char that came after one space
- g: match all
- match => match.toUpperCase(): replace with can take function, so; replace match with upper case match

It worked for converting the first letter of a string to capital letter and also works for the first letter of a string after space.

I added this expression that was supposed to cater for first letter of a string after space to the expression. The expression is `(?:- |\d\. ).*`

Combined with the first expression, it became:

```
text.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})|(?:- |\d\. ).*/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
```

The problem is that the method above doesn't work for the strings after the dash but still works for the strings after space.

Comment: There is another approach based on word boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `\d` is a digit, so your expression matches a `-`  or a digit followed by `.` ...
- `{1}` means one occurrence, which is the default anyways...

Try something like this:

```
/(^\w)|([-\s]\w)/g
```

Comment: What if I want to forcefully change all uppercase letters after the first letter to lowercase. Something like `MIKE-TYSON` to `Mike-Tyson`. Thank you

Comment: The regex does not explicitly match word boundaries. Thus it will miss anything which is not a blank or dash.

Comment: @Idris Try `text.toLowerCase().replace(...` for lowering the rest.

Answer (score 3):

A regex like ... [`/(?<=\b)\w/g`](https://regex101.com/r/hoBvrc/1/) or [`/(?<=\b)\p{L}/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/hoBvrc/2) ... which both use a [positive lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) for word boundaries but the second variant making use of [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) might be a more generic yet viable approach ...

```js
console.log(
  "mike-tyson wayne"
    .replace((/(?<=\b)\w/g), match => match.toUpperCase())
);
console.log(
  "MIKE-TYSON WAYNE"
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace((/(?<=\b)\p{L}/gu), match => match.toUpperCase())
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let text = "UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA-SAN DIEGO";
let pattern = /\w*/g;
let result = text.replace(pattern, function(word){
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
});

//result = University Of California-San Diego
```